# Adding (small) load to existing rafters with 2x4

Tags: roof, attic, fans

I am planning on installing a whole house fan (shown in the image below). The fan has a total system weight of 40 pounds and needs to be supported via metal and nylon straps to a beam as shown in the image below.

[image]

My roof does not have these cross beams. I am thinking about attaching a beam (2x4) via 10 penny nails as shown in the drawing below:

[image: proposed-beam]

My question is is there anything wrong with this approach? Could the load cause the roof to sag or any other problems I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably fine as far as weight goes. But I would not nail it, I would use construction screws (aka "deck screws") Pounding nails into the sides of those rafters may disturb your roof sheeting nails and or shingles, leading to leaks.